# Count call types by week, grouped by type, to identify trends

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I have another query that I am trying to group by week again.

So the first code excerpt below counts up all the call types based on a certain fixcode.  I'm trying to effectively group these by week and/or day so I can identify trends in the call numbers based on the call type.

```
SELECT count(*),substr(FIXCODE,1,4) FROM opencall
WHERE (opencall.status > 15 OR opencall.status = 6) 
and FIXCODE like 'HPS0%'
and trunc(to_date(substr(CLOSEDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '24-DEC-14' 
GROUP BY substr(FIXCODE,1,4)
```

This returns

```
Count   FixCode 
2425    HPS0
```

So this is a count of all the calls starting with a fixcode of HPS0 since January 1st.

I had a previous piece of code completed by another very helpful chap on StackOverflow, see below, which does group raw calls and counts them by week, but I don't know how to combine the two.

It would be great to subdivide the 2425 HPS0 calls into weeks so I can see how many of those calls were closed week by week to see a trend. Can anyone help? I'd love to do it by day too.

```
select 
'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW')) WEEK,
count(*) 
from opencall
where trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
group by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW')   
order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the value by week, add in the week to the `group by`:

```
SELECT to_char(closeddate, 'YYYY-IW'), substr(FIXCODE, 1, 4), COUNT(*)
FROM opencall
WHERE (opencall.status > 15 OR opencall.status = 6) 
and FIXCODE like 'HPS0%'
and trunc(CLOSEDATE) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '24-DEC-14' 
GROUP BY to_char(closeddate, 'YYYY-IW'), substr(FIXCODE, 1, 4)
ORDER BY  to_char(closeddate, 'YYYY-IW')
```

Presumably `closeddate` is already a date, so you don't need to convert it back to a date.